# Is using exec() to execute code read from a text file bad practice?

Tags: python, exec

I am trying to read data from a text file, where a variable name is listed and a value is given to it.

e.g

```
manufacturer_num = 12345
```

I want to store this data into already initialized class variables. The name of the class variables are the same as the variables in the text file. Is it bad practice to use exec() in this case, and is there a better way to do this?

Below is the code I currently have. The text file is very long.

```
 def initialize(self):
        f = open(self.path, "r")
        for x in range(self.init_var_len):
            line = f.readline()
            if "=" in line:
                split_string = line.split("=")
                split_string[0] = split_string[0].strip()
                split_string[1] = split_string[1].strip()
                exec("self." + split_string[0] + "=" + "type(self." + split_string[0] + ")(" + "'"+split_string[1]+"'"+")")

        f.close()

        for each in self.__dict__.keys():
            print eval("self." + each)
```

Comment: Using `exec` is not good practice. You're already going to all the trouble of splitting out the variable name and value, so you'd be better off just storing those yourself, e.g. in a dictionary or as class attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES. Using `exec` is bad practice.**

`exec` can execute **arbitrary** code. The most important question is do you always implicitly trust the input files? The answer should be [no](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) unless you're using this code one time on data you personally are producing right now.

The following is an example of an input file that your code would read and then immediately delete your whole hard drive.

```python
manufacturer_num = 12345'); import os; os.system('rm -rf /
```

(For obvious reasons I did not actually test this.)

Even if you use your code on data you personally produce, but in the future, you risk hurting yourself with a malformed input file you wrote for code half remembered.

Assuming your data format stays the same, and without diving into how you're using your class variables, here's how I would write the code.

```python
def initialize(self):
    with open(self.path, "r") as f:
        for x, line in enumerate(f):
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                continue  # Skip blank lines
            name, value = [s.strip() for s in line.split("=", maxsplit=1)]
            if '=' in value:
                raise ValueError(
                    f'Unexpected multiple "=" in line {x}: {line}')
            # Initialization depends on self.path. Don't let the file
            # overwrite it. Also, limit ourselves to class variables
            # because, hopefully, they're declared explicitly in the
            # code, and the OP said class variables.
            cls = type(self)
            if not hasattr(cls, name) or name == 'path':
                raise AttributeError(name)
            expected_type = type(getattr(cls, name))
            setattr(self, name, expected_type(value))
    # vars is the canonical way of accessing self.__dict__
    for name, value in vars(self).items():
        print(name, value)
```

Comment: thank you for this, reading how you would do it is making me realize some things I overlooked.